# Injecting Servics Fabric ServiceContext into Config implementations using DI

Tags: c#, autofac, azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to read my configuration from SF configuration using the 'ConfigurationPackage' that is available from any SF service context. My class looks like this:

```
internal class ServiceFabricDbConfiguration : IDbConnectionConfig
{
    private ConfigurationPackage _configurationPackage;

    public ServiceFabricDbConfiguration(ServiceContext context)
    {
        _configurationPackage = context.CodePackageActivationContext.GetConfigurationPackageObject("Config");
    }

    public string UserName =>
        _configurationPackage.Settings.Sections["Db_Configuration"]
            .Parameters[
                "Username"]
            .Value;
}
```

I'm using autofac as my DI container, and can register the above class by explicitly capturing a reference to the ServiceContext when i register it with the SF runtime:

```
ServiceRuntime.RegisterServiceAsync("ApiType",
                        context =>
                        {
                            Bootstrapper.SetContext(context);
                            return new Api(context);
                        })
                    .GetAwaiter()
                    .GetResult();
```

Is there a way that i can register the ServiceContext with the bootstrapper, ideally within the bootstrapper class?

I'm currently experimenting with using Autofac.ServiceFabric to register my actors/services, but that hides the ServiceContext so makes the above harder to achieve again (though does make it far easier to maintain clean autofac module definitions)

Comment: Not sure what your Bootstrapper class is, but regardless.. There's the static method `GetActivationContext()` in `FabricRuntime`. Can you not harness this?

Comment: I would, if you haven't already, seriously consider looking at the Service Fabric autofac extensions. It's im beta at the moment but I have been using it without issue. https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.ServiceFabric

Comment: Ah - i hadn't noticed FabricRuntime (Had been using FabricClient but ServiceContext isn't available through this) - thats perfect, thanks Mardoxx. If you add this as an answer i'll accept it. Yup - I'm just switching our projects to use Autofac.ServiceFabric, but i don't think they have a build in extension for this? [Apologies - Bootstrapper is the class with the autofac registrations]

Comment: What do you mean "build in extension"? There's a nuget package available here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.ServiceFabric Although I am not sure when he plans on releasing it proper! If you have a look at the closed issues on the git repository he has very helpfully answered some of my concerns and questions, these may be worth reading!

Comment: Sorry - i meant a built in extension for registering the ActivationContext with autofac - i'll add our own. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh I believe the RegisterActor/Service functions register the activation context, but only within the service's scope, not elsewhere. Not entirely an expert on DI though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the static method `GetActivationContext(`) in `FabricRuntime`. You could perhaps use this to inject the activation context.

There's also, in development, Autofac.ServiceFabric https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.ServiceFabric which may be of use to you. There's a blog post about it here https://alexmg.com/introducing-the-autofac-integration-for-service-fabric/ which also contains links to sample code! It's in pre-release (beta) at the moment but I have been using it without issue for the past few months.

Answer (score 1):

[PR  8](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.ServiceFabric/pull/8) makes the ServiceContext available in Autofac.ServiceFabric

Comment: Actually, no it doesn't. It uses a LifetimeScope to limit the availability of the ServiceContext to the instantiation of the service and doesn't make it available to other services registered within the Autofac container.